# Execute php file from bash script

Tags: php, bash

My below code works fine to execute a bash script in the *background* from PHP:

```
$cmd = "(touch $run_file && java -jar $trimmomatic SE -threads 8 $file $trimmed_file HEADCROP:5 && rm $run_file)";
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

What I want to add is to execute an external php file upon the completion of this command.

I tried this it but didn't work:

```
$cmd = "(touch $run_file && java -jar $trimmomatic SE -threads 8 $file $trimmed_file HEADCROP:5 && rm $run_file && php -f confirm.php)";
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
```

How can I make sure to execute `confirm.php` upon completion of the bash script?

Comment: give the full path of the source folder like /var/www/cloud/confirm.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while executing php script from bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700426/error-while-executing-php-script-from-bash)

Comment: The trivial solution is to not run it in the background.  If you need some other processing to continue on the PHP side while Bash runs the background command, you need to be more specific about how exactly the running PHP process should be notified when Bash is done with the background process. In real programming languages, you get a signal, but I don't know if that's available / reliable in PHP.

Comment: Maybe see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27071051/sigchild-not-catching-signal-when-child-process-dies

Comment: @tripleee If I don't send the command to the background with `&`, php waits for the command to be completed which may take hours. I catch the success or the failure of the command from the output files produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed my problem. I am posting here the solution if anybody else gets stuck at the same point as I did and desperately reach here.

In my `confirm.php` file, I included another file which contained functions as well as a Class object. The command line cannot execute methods in the Class object unless it is called from the original file with `echo` or explicitly passing the class to the command like `php -r 'include "Class_file.php"; echo MyClass::method(); '`. Since my `confirm.php` file depended on this Class for further processing, it failed here. This post helped me to figure it out:

[How do you execute a method in a class from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969735/how-do-you-execute-a-method-in-a-class-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

1)give the full path to php file

2)pass the second and third parameter and know the output and return value.

```
$cmd = "(touch $run_file && java -jar $trimmomatic SE -threads 8 $file $trimmed_file HEADCROP:5 && rm $run_file && php -f /var/www/cloud/confirm.php)";

exec($cmd . " 2>&1", $output, $return_var);

print_r($output);
 print_r($return_var);
```

Comment: If I don't send the command to the background with `&`, php waits for the command to be completed which may take hours.

Comment: This solution will still work if you put the background ampersand back on and remove the output and return vars.

Comment: I checked and it does not work, however that is not my problem, nor absolute path fixes it, hence this is not a solution. I don't care about the return values, my problem is `confirm.php` just doesn't get executed, although it works if I go to that page and refresh. The only way to save my day is to append the bash code in `confirm.php` to this page rather than calling it.